# How do you change the red-cd icon on WiX?

Tags: wix

In the Wix wizard there's a red CD icon here:

[image]

and here:

[image]

How do you change it?

I tried adding:

```
<WixVariable Id="WixUIInfoIco" Value="Dashman-setup-icon.bmp" />
<WixVariable Id="WixUIExclamationIco" Value="Dashman-setup-icon.bmp" />
```

but it had no effect.

Comment: @mcdon: do you want to add an answer? What I was missing is that those icons are not icons, just drawings on the banners.

Comment: For what it is worth: very nicely formatted and tersely phrased question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The red CD icons are part of the bitmaps used in the WixUIExtension. In the source code for [WixUIExtension](https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3/tree/develop/src/ext/UIExtension), you can view the [bitmaps](https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3/tree/develop/src/ext/UIExtension/wixlib/Bitmaps) it uses. From [UI Wizardy](https://www.firegiant.com/wix/tutorial/user-interface/ui-wizardry/):

```
<!-- WixUIBannerBmp 493 by 58 pixels,
     this bitmap will appear at the top of all
     but the first page of the installer-->
<WixVariable Id="WixUIBannerBmp" Value="path\banner.bmp" />

<!-- WixUIDialogBmp 493 by 312 pixels,
     this bitmap will appear on
     the first page of the installer.-->
<WixVariable Id="WixUIDialogBmp" Value="path\dialog.bmp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

IsWiX has project templates that pick up where the rather terse project templates from WiX leave off.  Out of the box you get a Code and Resources folder and a series of WiX fragments that define standard things such as MajorUpgrades,  common AppSearch/LaunchConditions and pulling in WiXUI with allowances for easily injecting a custom dialog by simply uncommenting out a line of XML.

https://github.com/iswix-llc/iswix/tree/main/Application/IsWiX2022AddIn/VotiveMSISolutionTemplate/SetupProjectTemplate

As the project coordinator I might be biased, but I just finished doing a bunch of UI work that previously I would have only dared doing in InstallShield.

Comment: 1. Link is broken 2. Comment does not answer the initial question

Comment: 5 year old link fixed.  It does answer the question as it shows an example .wixproj structure and msbuild to use them. Additionally if you poke around it shows how to do it with wix v4 SDK style projects also.